# Serial ports in Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, serial-communication

So I need to read some streaming data from /dev/ttyACM0 in Ubuntu.

However I'm a Windows guys so I'm looking for something like PuTTY so I can point, click and make my problem go away.

How do I get streaming data from a com port, or in this case /dev/ttyACM0 which is a USB cable working as CDC?  I just want to confirm that the device is sending what I think it should be sending.

Comment: fire up minicom (maybe not installed by default, but it should be available in most distributions)

Comment: This really belongs to Ubuntu.sx. Basic app question, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently putty is available on Ubuntu https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/putty/ . So, if you installed that you may get the same user experience you are used to from Windows. Alternatively minicom is probably one of the most common alternative ( http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Setting_up_Minicom_in_Ubuntu ).